# How do I map data from columns to rows?

Tags: google-sheets

In Google spreadsheet, how do I map data from columns to rows?

For example, if I have the following data:

> A1=Mary
>   A2=John
>   A3=Kelly

and I want them to populate `B5`, `C5`, `D5` in the same row, what formula should I use to do this for a large set of data?

Answer (score 0):

Use next formula in `B5` and drag it to the right:

```
=OFFSET($A$1;COLUMN(B5)-COLUMN($A$1)-1;0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, I would simply use this formula in `B5`:

```
=TRANSPOSE(A1:A3)
```

Comment: `there is something wrong with people who downvote just because they think their answer is better` [hmmmmmmm](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21343416/how-do-i-map-data-from-columns-to-rows/21343486#comment33150815_21891828)